# Feathers authentication not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I created authentication for my node project with feathers. I want to do admin's panel based on mongodb. I added new insert to mongo with email and password and for example I added in index file something like this:

```
app.authenticate({
    strategy: 'jwt',
      'email': "myemail",
      'password': "mypassword"
    }).then(function(result){
      console.log('Authenticated!', result);
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.error('Error authenticating!', error);
    });
```

Every time I get this message:

```
Error authenticating! Object { type: "FeathersError", name: "NotAuthenticated", message: "No auth token", code: 401, className: "not-authenticated", data: Object, errors: Object, stack: "NotAuthenticated: No auth token    …" }
```

My schema and model is correct. For verify provided is an email and password.

How to use feathers authentication properly? What an address should I use to send login (email) and password for login script and how to verify if user is logged?

In short words, I would like to use login form in combination with mongodb. After successfull login the user gets a token JWT. Next request is send as token JWT.

Comment: The `strategy` should be `local`, not `jwt`.

Comment: After changed it works now.